# How to output request header expranation into OpenAPI documents

Tags: swagger, fastapi, openapi

In my opinion, we can write for request header for the following string,

```
paths:
  /ping:
    get:
      summary: Checks if the server is alive
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: X-Request-ID
          schema:
            type: string
            format: uuid
          required: true
```

How is write the like code in FastAPI cases?

Comment: Oh, I see. OK not at al

Answer (score 0):

I followed the above mentioned link way
I'm happy if it helps you

```
@router.get(
"/code/{code}",
summary="codecheck",
description="code check with token check",
responses={
    st.HTTP_200_OK: {
        "content": {"application/txt": {
            "example": "code check was successful"
        }}
    },
    st.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST: {
        "content": {"application/json": {
            "example": "Request header is empty"
        }}
        },
    st.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN: {
        "content": {"application/json": {
            "example": "a-token is unmatched"
        }}
        },
    st.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: {
        "content": {"application/json": {
            "example": "Server internal error"
        }}
        }
    })
async def code_check(
code: str, request: Request,
a_token: str|None=Header(default=None)):
ctl = mainctl()
res: Response_data = await ctl.code(code, request)
if res.status_code == st.HTTP_200_OK: return res.text
raise HTTPException(status_code=res.status_code, detail=res.detail)
```

I just added "a_token: str|None=Header(default=None)"
response_data is my own class using pydantic, by the way

FastAPI adding Header detail to openapi document